# Remote application in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am using ubuntu for development. And I want to test my application on IE. So, instead of remote desktop I want to access IE as remote application from other windows machine. So the other guy whose working on windows machine can continue with his work and I can also test my application.

Are there any ways to access IE as remote application between windows and ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use VirtualBox in Ubuntu to create Windows virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you just need ie to test your applications, is to use ie running wine for ubuntu See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SeamlessVirtualization).

Answer (score 0):

FreeRdp just allows that. It is a bit buggy for me under Ubuntu Unity with nvidia proprietary drivers..

https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/RemoteApp

A couple of nice tools to set it up easily:

- on the Linux side is WinConn (search google I can't post more than two links)
- on the Windows side: https://sites.google.com/site/kimknight/remoteapptool